# how to count the number of pixels having certain values in a binary file using R?

Tags: r

I have a binary file that with dim of 1440*720 which equals 1036800 pixel.

I would like to know:

> How many pixels out of the total number of pixels that have values above 0.5?

Here's my code to read from the binary file:

```
    conne <- file("C:fined.bin","rb")
    sd<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
    y<-t(matrix((data=sd), ncol=1440, nrow=720))
```

Comment: where's the data? And what's the question?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading it right? I get all elements of `sd` and `y` to be `NaN`

Comment: I uploaded another file(edited).I still wonder why you got NAN

Comment: Can you show a `head(sd)`? It still gives me `NaN`. I suppose its the difference in our architectures (mine is 64-bit). I'll check it out. It helps to see your data to know when I get it right.

Comment: yes, you're right, my bad! sorry for the confusion.

Comment: to answer your question it is simply `sum(sd[is.finite(sd)] > 0.5)`

Comment: Don't use "sd" for your variable, because of potential conflicts with the R-function `sd` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `NaN` values before you count them.

```
sum(sd[!is.nan(sd)] > 0.5)
# [1] 104601
```

For info on the number of non-numeric values, use `table`.

```
table(sd > 0.5, useNA = "always")

# FALSE   TRUE   <NA> 
# 103341 104601 828858
```

Or `count` from the `plyr` package, for the results in a data frame form.

```
count(sd > 0.5)
#       x   freq
# 1 FALSE 103341
# 2  TRUE 104601
# 3    NA 828858
```

Comment: one question: If I have a vector `x <- c(1,2,NaN,NaN,NA,NA)` and I do `table(x, useNA="always")` then it tabulates `NaN` as `NaN` and `NA` as `NA` separately with count of 2 each. Then why does this give the name `<NA>` here instead of `NaN`? Any idea?

Comment: Well done.  Pointless option:  `sum(is.na(sd))` also returns the number of NA values.